# Magento2 : Protected function override with di:compile issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I want to override block `protected function _prepareLayout()` function from `\Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History`

I have created di.xml file for same

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History" 
            type="Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Orderhistory"/>
```

Block File: Orderhistory.php

```
<?php

  namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Order;

 class Orderhistory extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\History
```

{

```
protected $_coreRegistry = null;

protected $_salesData = null;

private $adminHelper;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Helper\Data $salesData
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Helper\Admin $adminHelper
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Sales\Helper\Data $salesData,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Magento\Sales\Helper\Admin $adminHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
    $this->_salesData = $salesData;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->adminHelper = $adminHelper;
}
/**
* @Override Buttton
*/
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    $onclick = "historyValidate.validation('" . $this->getSubmitUrl() . "');";
    $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button::class
    )->setData(
        ['label' => __('Submit Comment'), 'class' => 'action-save action-secondary', 'onclick' => $onclick]
    );
    $this->setChild('order_history_button', $button);
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}
/**
 * Get stat uses
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getStatuses()
{
    $state = $this->getOrder()->getState();
    $statuses = $this->getOrder()->getConfig()->getStateStatuses($state);
    return $statuses;
}

/**
 * Check allow to send order comment email
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function canSendCommentEmail()
{
    return $this->_salesData->canSendOrderCommentEmail($this->getOrder()->getStore()->getId());
}

/**
 * Retrieve order model
 *
 * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('sales_order');
}

/**
 * Check allow to add comment
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function canAddComment()
{
    return $this->_authorization->isAllowed('Magento_Sales::comment') && $this->getOrder()->canComment();
}

/**
 * Submit URL getter
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSubmitUrl()
{
    return $this->getUrl('sales/*/addComment', ['order_id' => $this->getOrder()->getId()]);
}

/**
 * Customer Notification Applicable check method
 *
 * @param  \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History $history
 * @return bool
 */
public function isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Status\History $history)
{
    return $history->isCustomerNotificationNotApplicable();
}

/**
 * Replace links in string
 *
 * @param array|string $data
 * @param null|array $allowedTags
 * @return string
 */
 public function escapeHtml($data, $allowedTags = null)
 {
    return $this->adminHelper->escapeHtmlWithLinks($data, $allowedTags);
 }
 }
```

While i am doing di:compile we are getting below error??

[image]

If anyone know how we can resolved this issue???

Comment: you have not inject your construct right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace your construct with below code:

```
 public function __construct(
\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
\Magento\Sales\Helper\Data $salesData,
\Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
\Magento\Sales\Helper\Admin $adminHelper,
array $data = []
) {

parent::__construct($context,$salesData,$registry,$adminHelper, $data);

 }
```

and remove generated folder

> rm -rf generated/*

and check after clearing cache

Comment: @Rutvee

I have a resolved an issue without making changes in construct as you suggested.  My previous code working fine now maybe there was an with caching.

Your answer will be right when we have to pass data on parent constructor. but I don't want to do that. Thank you for your input for same. :)